# Getting StackOverflow error during sonar scanner execution

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Getting the following stack overflow error log during one of the sonar scanner execution

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.google.common.collect.Hashing.smearedHash(Hashing.java:51)
    at com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap$Inverse.get(HashBiMap.java:545)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.GrammarBuilderInterceptor.actionForRuleKey(GrammarBuilderInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visitNonTerminal(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:81)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visit(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:72)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.convertChildren(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:129)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visitNonTerminal(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:119)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visit(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:72)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visitNonTerminal(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:89)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visit(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:72)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visitNonTerminal(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:89)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visit(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:72)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visitNonTerminal(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:89)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visit(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:72)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.convertChildren(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:129)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visitNonTerminal(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:119)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visit(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:72)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visitNonTerminal(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:89)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visit(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:72)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visitNonTerminal(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:89)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visit(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:72)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.convertChildren(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:129)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visitNonTerminal(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:119)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visit(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:72)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visitNonTerminal(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:89)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visit(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:72)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.convertChildren(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:129)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visitNonTerminal(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:119)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visit(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:72)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visitNonTerminal(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:89)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visit(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:72)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.convertChildren(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:129)
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Analysis is triggered in linux machine.

Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: What language are you analysing ? what is the version of the plugin of that language installed on your machine ?

Comment: I'm analyzing Java and Js files with Sonar Java 4.12.0.11033 and Sonar JS 3.1.1 (build 5128). SonarQube version 6.6

Comment: Im getting the same in my Java project using plugin sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar and SonarQube version: 6.7.0.

Comment: Same here, last java plugin, i'm using java 10